# Threading error using Atlas in numpy under Linux

Tags: linux, numpy, multiprocessing, runtime-error, atlas

I have a multi-process (not multi-thread!) application using the multiprocess module running on a Linux box.
This application uses the `numpy.linalg.solve` function, and if I try to create to many processes, then I get the error:

```
assertion !pthread_create( &(ROOT->pid), ATTR, ROOT->fun, ROOT ) failed, line 84 of file /build/buildd-atlas_3.8.4-9-amd64-jk6dgk/atlas-3.8.4/build/atlas-base/../..//src/pthreads/misc/ATL_thread_tree.c
```

Note that before I started using functions from `numpy.linalg`, I haven't had any problem.

Any idea what the problem may be?

**Edit**: I tried to use `scipy.linalg.solve` and the problem is the same!

**Edit**: By replacing atlas with blas, the problem disappears. So it really seems the issue is within atlas

Comment: It seems bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=766168

Comment: The error is the same, the context is different as I don't have a multi-threaded program and also I am not using Red-Hat.

Answer (score 3):

It just happens that the ATLAS developer recently answered that question here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/math-atlas/support-requests/873/

Note: I'm assuming you have ATLAS 3.10 installed.

This one has been bugging me for a while too. And if you have the same problem as mine, then it's highly likely that:

1. ATLAS was built on another machine than the one you're running this on
2. This build machine has more cores than your machine
3. ATLAS 3.10 doesn't know how to handle a lower number of cores than the number it had at build time and generate an exception.

The solution is to build ATLAS on a machine with a number of core lower or equal than your current machine.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Interesting. I don't know if this is my problem though. If this is the case, shouldn't the problem happen all the time? Currently, it happens only if I am using all the cores already by launching many processes at once. Also, in this case, is there a way to prevent ATLAS from using multiprocessing altogether?

Comment: Well I get the exact same error as yours if libraries use affinity. They link your compiled program to a particular machine / cpus. I've got similar problems with OpenBlas that seems to be fixed (I'm trying to switch to openblas indeed). Comping against libsatlas instead of libtatlas should prevent atlas from multithreading.